# MYSQL/PHP join many-to-many, fetch posts with their all categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 table

blogposts table, categories table, joins table.

```
SELECT post_id,
       post_title,
       post_text,
       post_poster,
       post_date,
       post_slug,
       category_name,
       user_name
       
FROM blogposts_categories_join

INNER JOIN blogposts ON post_id = bcj_post_id
INNER JOIN categories ON bcj_category_id = category_id
INNER JOIN users ON post_user = user_id
GROUP BY post_id
```

This is my query and I want to fetch posts for home page. everything is working but, the fetched data have only one category and I want to make something like this:

#### Posted in: general, news, health

How must I change my query to get posts, with all categories?

Comment: Change INNER JOIN TO RIGHT JOIN before blogposts

Comment: please provide DDL and some data. May be in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already grouping by post, you could just use a `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the categories, comma separated, something like (the untested);

```
SELECT post_id,
       post_title,
       post_text,
       post_poster,
       post_date,
       post_slug,
       GROUP_CONCAT(category_name) category_names,
       user_name
FROM blogposts_categories_join
INNER JOIN blogposts ON post_id = bcj_post_id
INNER JOIN categories ON bcj_category_id = category_id
INNER JOIN users ON post_user = user_id
GROUP BY post_id
```